# When is Windows Services executable unloaded?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services

At what point is the executable that runs a windows service unloaded?

For example in c#, a normal implementation of a Windows Service would be to create an exe with a class that implements `ServiceBase` e.g.

```
public class SlicifyClientNodeService : ServiceBase
{
    public static DateTime BootTime = DateTime.Now;

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        //start running
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        //stop running
    }
}
```

When the service is started/stopped from the services control panel, the onstart/onstop methods are called, but its not clear when a static variable like BootTime would be reinitialised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, for executables that implement only a single service, the process will be terminated each time the service is stopped and relaunched when it is next started.

However, the documentation for [`ServiceMain`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685138%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) implies that it is possible for a service to be stopped and then restarted within the same process, in which case static variables will not be reinitialized.  Presumably this can only happen if the stop and start requests are very close together, and I rather suspect that in fact it can't happen even then.

Regardless, I would recommend that you code defensively and avoid depending on this behaviour; there might be special cases where it varies, or it might change in future versions of Windows.